# Django save multiple foreign keys to database with multiple upload

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am a newbie in Django and I am looking for the best workaround on how to deal with this problem.

I have these 3 **Models:**

```
class Rigs(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    featured_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Gallery(models.Model):
    rigs = models.ForeignKey(Rigs, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='galleries')
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Specs(models.Model):
    cpu = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    motherboard = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rigs = models.ForeignKey(Rigs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cpu
```

I am using this library for the multi-uploading of images (https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload), so basically I structured my **Forms** similar to what the document states:

```
class SpecsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Specs
        fields = ('rigs', 'motherboard')

class RigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rigs
        fields = ('name','featured_img')

    gallery_image = MultiMediaField(
        min_num=1,
        max_num=3,
        max_file_size=1024*1024*5,
        media_type='image'
    )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(RigForm, self).save(commit)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['gallery_image']:
            Gallery.objects.create(file=each, rigs=instance)
        return instance
```

As well as my **Views:**

```
class newrig(CreateView):
 model = Rigs
 form_class = RigForm
 template_name = 'flexrigapp/newrig.html'
 success_url = '?success'
```

My problem is that I couldn't figure out how to include the SpecsForm on my HTML Form as well as save it on my database with the correct Foreign Key.

I have already tried transferring this one on my views with some changes but still no good.

```
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(RigForm, self).save(commit)
        for each in self.cleaned_data['gallery_image']:
            Gallery.objects.create(file=each, rigs=instance)
        return instance
```

Also, I tried a function based views instead of class based but the problem is that the multi-uploading validation doesn't work on this approach of mine or maybe my code is not correct.

The expected result is that data should be saved on its respective databases (Rigs, Specs, Gallery) with the proper Foreign key on the Specs and Gallery. Right now, I can only save the Rigs and Gallery.

This is Django 2.2.4, by the way.

**UPDATE**

I tried updating my Views to Function-Based View just like what @dirkgroten suggested.

```
def newrig(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
  rig_form = RigForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="rigs")
  specs_form = SpecsForm(request.POST, prefix="specs")
  if rig_form.is_valid() and specs_form.is_valid():
   rigs = rig_form.save()
   specs = specs_form.save(commit=False)
   specs.rigs = rigs
   specs.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect("?success")
 else:
  rig_form = RigForm(prefix="rigs")
  specs_form = SpecsForm(prefix="specs")
 return render(request, "flexrigapp/newrig.html", {'rig_form': rig_form,'specs_form': specs_form,})
```

No data is being saved on the database now. No error logs.

Comment: You can do two things; either add the fields for the specs model to your rigs form and in the form_valid method of your view manually create the specs model with the form’s cleaned_data fields. Or don’t use the CreateView but write your own view to handle both forms. Django’s generic CBVs are meant for a specific purpose. Don’t try to force them into doing something else.

Comment: Hi @dirkgroten, I tried updating my Views to a Function-based one but still no luck. Can't save data on the database anymore. Code updates can be found above. Cheers.

Comment: Your code looks good. What exactly is happening when you submit? Redirect to success view? Do you know for sure your forms are valid? Are you showing the form errors in your template when rendering them? Can you set a breakpoint in your view to see whether your forms are valid?